# Outlook ICS event invites sent from my site are being replaced by newer invites

Tags: outlook, icalendar, nodemailer

I'm using nodemailer to send ICS style calendar events to clients from a site. When a user receives an ICS invite from my site, the last event invite from my site is completely removed from their calendar. This only happens on Windows 7 running Outlook 2010. I have not yet found a definitive way to reproduce this error of other people's computers, however, as this system has been observed to be working on other Windows 7 + Outlook 2010 systems. I'm using NPM's ics-creator to construct the invites like so:

```
//med is mediator, meet is the meeting in question
 var e = cal.createICS({
          organizerEmail: "myuser@mysite.com",
          organizerName: "COMPANY resolutions",

          attendeeName: med.name,
          attendeeEmail: email,

          start: new Date(meet.start_time),
          end: new Date(meet.end_time),

          body: meet.case_desc, 
          subject: meet.case_name,
          location: "LOCATION",
          uuid: String(new Date().getTime()).substring(0,-9)


        }, "event");
```

Then the email is sent with this simple nodemailer configuration:

```
var mailOpts = {
              from: "resolutions@CLIENT.com",
              to: email, //med.email
              cc: "me@myCompany.com",
              subject: meet.title + " - UNIQUE IDENTIFIER",
              icalEvent: {
                method: "request",
                content: e.toString()
              }
            }
```

This is what happens when the particular problematic user receives one, then another invite from my site:

[image: Test1]

[image: Test2]

Answer (score 0):

I was using an example in the ics-creator NPM library to get the uuid. Turns out, the substring call:

```
     uuid: String(new Date().getTime()).substring(0,-9)
```

Was always null by the definition of the method. How did this ever work in the first place?